# Bootstrap "mobile" menu not showing on mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

so I am getting this weird behavior with my bootstrap menu on my site. When I open up my app on a mobile device (iPhone 4S, iPhone 6 plus, Galaxy S4) or in the Chrome emulator, it shows me the full version of the menu:
[image: On actual iPhone 6 Device] [image: iPhone 4 emulated on Chrome]

But, when on my desktop browser, I resize the window, it starts working, even though the width is greater here than in the devices:
[image: Smaller screen on desktop]

This is my code (I am using Bootstrap v3.2.0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <div class="">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/home');?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/logo.png');?>" id="mainLogo" /></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Red Bticino<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/setup/create');?>">Crear Nueva Red</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/setup/join');?>">Unirse a Red</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/setup/open');?>">Abrir Red</a></li>
                    <li><a id="leaveNet">Dejar esta Red</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Control del Hogar<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/device/all');?>">Dispositivos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/scene/home');?>">Escenarios</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/schedule');?>">Horarios</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle iconNav" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/settings/hour_simple');?>">Configuración Horaria</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/settings/network');?>">Configuración de Red</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#resetFactory" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resetFactory">Factory Reset</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/admin/users');?>">Gestionar Usuarios</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="iconNav"><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/welcome/help');?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Do you happen to find something wrong with my html code? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a viewport `meta` tag anywhere in your `<head>` section?

Comment: No, I don't. Just the basic doctype and css/js includes.

Comment: [Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) first next time. It warns about this exact error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your page's `<head>` section, add the following `meta` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Here's a little bit on how the viewport works, according to Google Developers:

> Without a viewport, mobile devices will render the page at a typical desktop screen width, scaled to fit the screen. Setting a viewport gives control over the page's width and scaling on different devices.

*Source:* https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport